# wide wired keyboard without numpad

Tags: keyboards

I'm looking for an *inexpensive* wide keyboard without a number pad. I'm not a gamer and  don't use media keys, don't need lights or anything like that. I have big stiff fingers, do a lot of writing and coding so all I want is alphanumeric, navigation, the basic F-keys.

Comment: If it doesn't have a number pad then it would be less wide than a board that has one. Can you clarify what you mean by "wide" because your requirements seem to contradict each other right now.

Comment: @Romen I want a wide board that does not 'waste' width on a number pad. I see many boards without a number pad and these are all 'compact' as if eliminating the number pad is a way of making the keyboard smaller. Not what I want.  I want lots of space for the alphabet keys.  Note: I *never* use the number pad so for me they are a waste of space. I see people use numpads and understand them to be very useful but I never use them so...

Comment: Do you mean you want the keys to have wider **spacing**? Not talking about the width of the whole keyboard? Or wider than standard keys? You should know that QWERTY keyboards are standardized so the keys are the same size and spacing on all keyboards. It sounds like you want something like a non-standard keyboard with large keys?

Comment: This looks like you want an oversized TKL keyboard, like https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1824728/logitech-mx-mechanical-mini-kailh-choc-brown-v2-azerty-fr.html but bigger?

Comment: I think the mention of no numpad is just because they see it as unnecessary extra width. The actual goal here is to get "wider keys" whatever that means, and if it has the numpad they think it would make the keyboard much larger than a normal one. You might have to take what you can get with or without a numpad because non-standard key sizes are hard to find.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://www.morekeyboard.com/)? It has a number pad though.